# How to keep a fixed UITextField below UITableView ?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, uitableview

I have been reading all over the web about this and still can't understand what is the proper way of handling the following:

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView inside it.

I want to display a FIXED UITextField below that tableview that will be visible all the time (separate from the tableview scrolling). This is the exact behavior of the iphone SMS app.

How should it be done?

I can add the UITextField as a complete separate view from the uitableview and place it below it, but then I have to manually adjust the various views and move them when the keyboard comes up.

Is this the right way to go ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Add another UIView at the bottom and adjust everything when the keyboard comes up and down.